# How can asynchronous server interfaces mapped to SOME/ IP be implemented in AUTOSAR classic?

Tags: autosar

I have to define a SOME/IP service in a AUTOSAR classic software component, which, beyond other things, triggers a (asynchronous) NVM operation.
After I receive the job finished notification in the same or another runnable (TBD), I have to give a response indicating whether this was successful.

Can, and if yes how, can I configure that a Runnable gets triggered from a call of the client/ server interface and continues to execute until end, but, when triggered from another interface or even a different Runnable, gives back the response to the SOME/IP call.

I have looked into the "Software Component Template", the "Specification of the RTE Software" and the "Specification of SOME/IP Transformer", but did not find an answer there.

Comment: You could create `WaitPoint` on which you runnable waits. Resolve that waitpoint from the callback  of your asynchronous operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem may best be solved by using a WaitPoint in the Runnable Entity serving the OperationInvokedEvent of your SOME/IP method:

- you can specify a time out value for the asynchronous call to the NvM operation. In case the timeout happens return an error.
- the WaitPoint.trigger attribute indicates the RTEEvent the WaitPoint is waiting for. In your case that would be the the AsynchronousServerCallReturnsEvent of the NvM operation call.
- If the WaitPoint unblocks the runnable uses Rte_Result() in order to retrieve the return value from your NvM Operation.

For details on WaitPoint see [AUTOSAR Classic Platform Software Component Template](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/standards/classic/22-11/AUTOSAR_TPS_SoftwareComponentTemplate.pdf)